# How to get the scalar value returned by eigen tensor's sqrt() function

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor, sqrt

```
Eigen::Tensor<float, 1> linear(2);
linear.setValues({3,4});
auto linear_square = linear * linear;
auto linear_square_sum = linear_square.sum().sqrt(); 
std::cout<<linear_square_sum<<std::endl; // 5

auto new_linear = linear.constant(linear_square_sum);
std::cout<<new_linear<<std::endl; // expected: [5,5]
```

The expected value of `linear_square_sum` is 5. Now the goal is to create a tensor that is the same size with `linear`, which shows in the last two code lines. Unfortunately, there's some bugs about the unmatched C++ type in the Eigen tensor's constant function as the required parameter type of constant is `scalar(int,float)`. So the question is how I can get the scalar value of the parameter `linear_square_sum`. I'd appreciated it if someone teaches me how to change the last two code lines.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Eigen documentation under ["Common Pitfalls"](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html) you'll see an explanation of why the Eigen Expression-Template style types don't mix well with `auto`.
So you should spell out the types explicitly.

But the actual issue is probably that linear_square_sum is a "0 dimensional Tensor" which is a valid reprentation of a Scalar according to the documentation. But it does not match the Scalar type of `linear` which is explicitly declared to be float.

You can access the underlying Scalar of a "0 dimensional Tensor" with the `operator()` overload that takes not arguments. So this is one possible solution.

```
using FTensor1 = Eigen::Tensor<float, 1>;
using FTensor0 = Eigen::Tensor<float, 0>;
FTensor1 linear(2);
linear.setValues({3,4});
FTensor1 linear_square = linear * linear;
FTensor0 linear_square_sum = linear_square.sum().sqrt(); 
std::cout<<linear_square_sum<<std::endl; // 5

auto new_linear = linear.constant(linear_square_sum());
std::cout<<new_linear<<std::endl; // expected: [5,5]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems to solve this question. However, what if the type of 'linear' is auto that is not explicitly known because I'm modifying the tensorflow core code in which the type of 'linear' is given in auto, which I know it can be definitely simplified into the row vector. Is there some other way for the auto type of linear. Thanks^_^

Comment: Is it possible to convert the type of 'linear_square_sum' to Eigen::Tensor<float, 1> or use the tensormap to map it a tensor?